# Includes not filtering as expected in Angular 5

Tags: typescript, include, angular5

I am trying to filter using includes to show states from addresses of a building. For example i want to show Washington only once even if it has ten buildings situated there

```
for (let i=0; i<=this.professional.hospital.length; i++) {
        if(this.professional.hospital[i].address && this.professional.hospital[i].address.length > 0) {
            if (this.states.includes(this.professional.hospital[i].address[0].state) === false) {
                this.states.push({label: this.professional.hospital[i].address[0].state,
                    value: this.professional.hospital[i].address[0].state
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

This is usually how i do it but it is adding the state even if its in the array
Any ideas guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (let i=0; i<this.professional.hospital.length; i++) {
        if(this.professional.hospital[i].address && this.professional.hospital[i].address.length > 0) {
            if (!this.states.find(x => x.value == this.professional.hospital[i].address[0].state)) {
                this.states.push({label: this.professional.hospital[i].address[0].state,
                    value: this.professional.hospital[i].address[0].state,
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

I figured it out. this is the way if anyone is ever stuck on it